# Recargar contenido html de navegador en vba

Tags: html, vba, script, navegador-web, internet-explorer-11

Tengo un codigo en vba que abre una pagina de ie. Obtengo el html y a continuacion pulso un bonton que se encuentra en un popup. Ese boton añade nuevo codigo a html de la pagina, con lo que al ser añadido después, no puedo acceder a pulsar otro boton del popup. Necesitaria recargar el codigo del navegador sin recargar la página para no perder ese popup y pulsarlo. Os pongo el codigo a continuación. Me es un poco urgente, si es posible, claro. Muchísimas gracias.

```
Sub openExplorer()
' --------------------------- VARS IE ---------------------
Dim ie As Object
Dim objDocucment As mshtml.HTMLDocument
Dim State As Integer

'--------------------------- PROGRAM OPEN_IE ---------------------
State = 0
Do Until State = 4
    DoEvents
    State = ie.readyState
Loop
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate "https://www1.anyWeb.html"
ie.Visible = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
 Write #1, "----- Print all html : "
For Each body In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("body")
    Write #1, body.innerHTML
Next
For Each body In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If botones.Title = "Si" Then
         botones.Click 'This button add new code html 
    End If
Next
' ----> Load new code html in browser here.



Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola Moses91, este sitio es en español, puedes traducir tu pregunta? o colocar tu [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) en StackOverFlow en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías esperar a que cargue la página (también después del botón).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub openExplorer()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www1.anyWeb.html"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        '.....

        .document.querySelector("button[title=Si]").Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        '....
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Entonces.......